# Search item using LIKE when they're saved with HTMLENTITIES

Tags: php, sql

I'm using latin special characters on my database. For exemple: 
The word "FLÁVIO" is saved like

```
fl&aacute;vio
```

I'm trying to use `LIKE` to search this item.. for example.. Users search for "Flávio" and I would like to return "flávio".

I tried to do something like this:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = htmlentities($search);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$search%';
```

The conversion is done, but when I put this `$search` on the SQL Query it doesn't match.

How can I fix? Thanks.

Comment: use utf8, it would be esier

Comment: The most sensible thing would be not to store them html-encoded. Can you fix it at that end?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is it case sensitivity? You can use [strtoupper](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) before searching.

Comment: VAR_DUMP result = string 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%fl&aacute;vio%'

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.?

Comment: I think you'll need a function to convert/translate those html entities to the corresponding character, check this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,246527,246527

Comment: Thanks, John! I'll check this link out!

Answer (score -2):

Just an idea, but have you tried using REGEXP?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '$search'";
```

I wonder if that will make a difference.